# Not able to list files in a cvs module in command line?

Tags: cmd, cvs

I executed the same cvs command on two machines and it worked only on 1 of them. The command is:

```
cvs  -d %CVSROOT%  ls "module"
```

* In the first machine it returned me the files directly under the module.
* I added -R parameter to make the call recursive and this time I got an error:

> cvs [ls aborted]: Remote server does not support rls.  Requested
>   options not available.

In the second machine I directly got an error even without adding the -R command:
cvs [ls aborted]: server does not support ls

Both machines are connecting to the same server and same module and same CVS root and same CVSNT version.

Comment: I suggest to enclose `%CVSROOT% ` also in double quotes, i.e. use `"%CVSROOT%"` and make sure this environment variable really contains the expected value on execution, i.e. look on the command line with `echo cvs -d "%CVSROOT%" ls "module" & pause`. And I suggest to specify `"C:\Full path to CVS binaries folder\cvs.exe"` instead of just `cvs` to make sure the right application is executed and not whatever is found by Windows command processor with file name `cvs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually used rlog command to get a list of all files on the CVS server. The rlog command worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

The first dynamic argument in the command is %CVSROOT%, please try to find if it contains proper value. If the path is wrong, then you will get this error message.

If that value is proper, then just give ls without module name, so that you can eliminate the wrong module name issue.